# Missing the viewbased application template in xcode4

Tags: xcode4

I've been reading around on iPhone development and it seems like there's supposed to be a template called viewbased appliation when you create a new project which my xcode4 is missing. 
 Am I missing something from my install that I'm unaware of or are these articles referencing an old way of doing things?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Xcode has replace the viewbased template with the singleview template. And they have introduced the 'storyboard' approach, which you should look into because it's quite nice to work with. As far as the viewbased application though, it is gone and has been replaced with the singleview template